<SessionProvider/> doesn't respond to session updates
An image of layout.tsx
This is currently the code:
I used to pass the session to the Nav and UserModal as a prop, and it worked properly (since props respond to direct changes in the parent), but then i started using useSession() hook, and with that, when I login into the app, and the session does update (I can see that when I added a console.log to layout.tsx , it was null before logging in and then became a valid session), and the session inside the nav and the modal just stay null until I refresh.
What are the possible solutions for this?
I tried to update the session by logging in and successfully did so, but the update didn't reflect on the children of the session provider

Please avoid using code images. If possible, provide a complete example of your code that we can run for testing purposes, including the version of next and next-auth. If the session is getting null, it may be because the get session is failing and returning a 500/504 status, check your browser's network or server console. Another test is to move the SessionProvider above the CartProvider, just to be sure.

To simplify it, I have a session provider inside my layout.tsx file, and inside it I call 'auth()' by next-auth-5 as follows : const session = await auth() , afterwards, i use a  and nest my  inside of it, so I could use the useSession() hook , issue is, even though the session is being updated after I log in, which is evident If i log the session in layout.tsx, the session doesn't get updated in the children inside the  unless I reload the page

If i passed the session as react props to the  however, it does update as soon as I log in and the session that I'm getting with const session = await auth() updates

Yes, I understood what you said, but just saying it like that I would say that everything is fine, because SessionProvider updates all the children below, all useSession should return the session correctly. In short, we need a complete code sample to understand what is happening.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
